# owl carousel with thumbnails, possible?

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel

What need to do:
[image]

I am using `vue-owl-carousel2`

I don't find it in the documentation to make it possible.

Vue 2.5.16 version.
Or is it better to use swiper?